# Which WooCommerce hook or function that receives the payment response by billet and credit card?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, hook-woocommerce

I am implementing an integration using woocommerce. I would like to send the purchase made by the user to other system after the payment of the billet or credit card is confirmed. Does anyone know where I can get this return of the payment and how do I get the purchase's transaction ID?

I tried the code below, but the function doesn't seem to have been called;

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete','send_payed_order_to_omie');
function send_payed_order_to_omie($order_id)
{
  /*Código que envia a venda para o ERP*/
}
```

Comment: Was does mean payment by billet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct hook for payed orders *(excluding "bacs" (bank wire) and "cheque" payments that requires to be manually complete when payment is received)*.

You can see that in the [**source code**](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.0.0/includes/class-wc-order.php#L99-L144) of `WC_Order` `payment_complete()` method *(used by all payment methods)*, where `woocommerce_payment_complete` hook is located, that set the transaction ID *(when it's returned by the payment gateway)*.

To get the transaction ID you can use the `WC_Order` `get_transaction_id()` method.

So your code will be:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete','send_payed_order_to_omie');
function send_payed_order_to_omie( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    $transaction_id = $order->get_transaction_id();

    // Your other code
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you @LoicTheAztec